# Error deploying WAR file to Jboss EAP 6.0, which works under JBOSS AS 7.1

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

We are working on our new system which is built using Jboss, Spring and Hibernate and at the moment we're in the progress of migrating from AS 7.1 to EAP 6.0.

For reasons unknown to us the deployment fails when deploying to the EAP 6.0 server, but works perfectly fine under AS 7.1(both on our local machines and our local test-server).

In short, we get the following error:

```
"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./Web" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./Web: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"},
"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"Web.war\".jboss.security.jacc Missing[JBAS014861: ]"]
```

Furthermore, we have the console log, see below for further information. We've found https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-5222, and as far as we understand there is a fix included which gives more detailed error information, alas we can't update/upgrade at the moment.

So my humble question is, does anyone have an idea on how to solve this issue?

```
    =========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

10:30:54,539 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.2.GA-redhat-1
10:30:54,896 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA-redhat-1
10:30:55,002 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.0.0.GA (AS 7.1.2.Final-redhat-1) starting
10:30:56,296 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.4.GA-redhat-1
10:30:56,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
10:30:56,312 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.4.GA-redhat-1
10:30:56,322 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.8.GA-redhat-1
10:30:56,362 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
10:30:56,369 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
10:30:56,393 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
10:30:56,506 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
10:30:56,510 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.11.Final-redhat-1)
10:30:56,559 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
10:30:56,568 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.9.Final-redhat-1
10:30:56,598 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011906: Activating OSGi Subsystem
10:30:56,602 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
10:30:56,622 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
10:30:56,692 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
10:30:56,719 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
10:30:56,920 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.4.GA-redhat-1
10:30:57,138 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Expired Entry Monitor) ARJUNA012210: Unable to use InetAddress.getLocalHost() to resolve address.
10:30:57,167 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-/0.0.0.0:8080
10:30:57,413 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
10:30:57,632 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments
10:30:57,644 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on 0.0.0.0:4447
10:30:57,645 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on 0.0.0.0:9999
10:30:57,763 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
10:30:57,763 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.0.0.GA (AS 7.1.2.Final-redhat-1) started in 3619ms - Started 133 of 212 services (78 services are passive or on-demand)
10:33:36,236 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Web.war"
10:33:41,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 4.0)
10:33:41,306 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
10:33:41,404 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011907: Register module: Module "deployment.Web.war:main" from Service Module Loader
10:33:51,310 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error listenerStart
10:33:51,311 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context [/Web] startup failed due to previous errors
10:33:51,335 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./Web: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./Web: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_06]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_06]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_06]

10:33:51,542 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "Web.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./Web" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./Web: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"Web.war\".jboss.security.jacc Missing[JBAS014861: <one or more transitive dependencies>]"]}
10:33:51,565 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011908: Unregister module: Module "deployment.Web.war:main" from Service Module Loader
10:33:51,675 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Web.war in 132ms
```

Updated: Here's some more log. Note that this is running OpenJDK 1.7, instead of the regular version. We've tried both of them but the issue remains.

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

14:12:59,719 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.2.GA-redhat-1
14:13:00,028 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA-redhat-1
14:13:00,111 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.0.0.GA (AS 7.1.2.Final-redhat-1) starting
14:13:01,469 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.4.GA-redhat-1
14:13:01,488 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
14:13:01,493 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.4.GA-redhat-1
14:13:01,505 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.8.GA-redhat-1
14:13:01,540 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
14:13:01,546 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
14:13:01,560 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
14:13:01,674 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
14:13:01,699 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.11.Final-redhat-1)
14:13:01,715 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
14:13:01,729 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
14:13:01,735 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.9.Final-redhat-1
14:13:01,757 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011906: Activating OSGi Subsystem
14:13:01,838 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
14:13:01,848 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
14:13:01,898 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
14:13:02,153 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.4.GA-redhat-1
14:13:02,383 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-/0.0.0.0:8080
14:13:02,530 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Expired Entry Monitor) ARJUNA012210: Unable to use InetAddress.getLocalHost() to resolve address.
14:13:02,754 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
14:13:02,895 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on 0.0.0.0:9999
14:13:02,897 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on 0.0.0.0:4447
14:13:02,908 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/EAP-6.0.0.GA/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments
14:13:03,018 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
14:13:03,019 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.0.0.GA (AS 7.1.2.Final-redhat-1) started in 3697ms - Started 133 of 212 services (78 services are passive or on-demand)
14:13:50,537 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Web.war"
14:13:55,458 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 4.0)
14:13:55,462 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
14:13:55,598 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011907: Register module: Module "deployment.Web.war:main" from Service Module Loader
14:14:01,556 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Error listenerStart
14:14:01,556 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Context [/Web] startup failed due to previous errors
14:14:01,575 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./Web: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./Web: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05-icedtea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05-icedtea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05-icedtea]

14:14:01,782 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "Web.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./Web" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./Web: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"Web.war\".jboss.security.jacc Missing[JBAS014861: <one or more transitive dependencies>]"]}
14:14:01,794 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011908: Unregister module: Module "deployment.Web.war:main" from Service Module Loader
14:14:01,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Web.war in 152ms
14:15:39,916 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/] has not been started
14:15:39,935 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-/0.0.0.0:8080
14:15:39,935 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-/0.0.0.0:8080
14:15:39,945 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011503: Restored bootstrap log handlers
14:15:39,950 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] ARJUNA032018: Destroying TransactionManagerService
14:15:39,951 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] ARJUNA032014: Stopping transaction recovery manager
14:15:39,965 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss EAP 6.0.0.GA (AS 7.1.2.Final-redhat-1) stopped in 6ms
```

Comment: From the log I cannot see any deployment related errors, but the jboss server cannot start up properly.

Comment: @Quincy The server starts just fine if there's no deployment available. The error occurs when I try to enable the deployment, or from the management console, or when adding the war file deployment folder. Either way it's the same issue.

Comment: Porting from Jboss 7 to EAP 6 should not be hard. Have you checked if all the configuration you used in jboss 7 had been set on EAP 6? e.g. library modules

Comment: I agree it should be a breeze. Yeah, we've made extensive comparisons between the configurations and the modules, in order to make sure that everything is "identical". Still no luck though.

Comment: Hm... have you tried to use the full config file `standalone-full.xml` instead?

Comment: Yes, we have. Same result there. I will take another look at it and see if I can give you some detailed results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ensure that you are not using **Spring Framework** versions between `2.5` and `3.0.1`. These are known to be incompatible with all versions of **JBoss** from `5.0` or so and newer;

Use below command and let me know the the status.

```
standalone.sh -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. The version of spring that we are using is 3.1.1, so in that should be fine. Unfortunately we still get the same error.

However, we noticed something very peculiar if we insert dummy values in our configuration file for hibernate and our ldap connection, the deployment works. Naturally the application is useless since nothing works without the database connection. What could be the cause of that?

Comment: I realized that I haven't gotten back to this question. Your solution to use the *standalone.sh -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false* was correct, it showed us the underlying problem which was a database error. Since we have Hibernate configured to validate the database it failed and just rolled everything back.

Comment: @SpiritBreaker I am facing the same issue. Can you please let me know where to use the command standalone.sh -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false ?

Answer (score 1):

We faced similar issue, with `JBoss AS 7.2.0 final` and `Spring 3.2.8`. In our case we missed the setting of spring's active profile to point to **Jboss7**. Once we set this the context was resolved, deployment was successful.

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dspring.profiles.active=jboss7
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My version was having a hard time accepting the -Dspring.profiles.active=jboss7 value (Invalid value error) .. So I found somewhere else on the net `export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=jboss7` and this works in place of the JAVA_OPTS if that errors on you.