# JBOSS 7.1.1 can´t deploy ear file

Tags: jboss7.x

Hi at all i hope you can help me. I Have a problem with JBOSS 7.1.1.
I can´t deploy an ear file in JBOSS 7, but with JBOSS 5 it was successfull.

```
13:54:44,894 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4)MSC00001:Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."tcentw.ear".STRUCTURE:org.jboss.msc.service.StartExceptioninservicejboss.deployment.unit."tcentw.ear".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "tcentw.ear"at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]

at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]

at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]

Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011060: Failed to process children for EAR ["/C:/splm/JBOSS/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/tcentw.ear"]        

at org.jboss.as.ee.structure.EarStructureProcessor.deploy(EarStructureProcessor.java:218)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]

   ... 5 more

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file 

at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:154) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:118) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
at org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem.<init>(JavaZipFileSystem.java:97)
at org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem.<init>(JavaZipFileSystem.java:83)
at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:408)
at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:434)
at    org.jboss.as.ee.structure.EarStructureProcessor.mount(EarStructureProcessor.java:223)
at org.jboss.as.ee.structure.EarStructureProcessor.createResourceRoot(EarStructureProcessor.java:242)
at org.jboss.as.ee.structure.EarStructureProcessor.deploy(EarStructureProcessor.java:176)
 ... 6 more


13:54:44,925 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 5) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "tcentw.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => "jboss.deployment.unit.\"tcentw.ear\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"tcentw.ear\".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"tcentw.ear\""}}

13:54:44,941 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment tcentw.ear in 5ms

13:54:44,941 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 5) JBAS014774: Service status reportJBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."tcentw.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."tcentw.ear".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "tcentw.ear"
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: check if this is what you are facing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083848/error-deploying-war-file-to-jboss-eap-6-0-which-works-under-jboss-as-7-1

Comment: No sry, but thanks for help.